# Creating .sat files for .jpg tiles?

Tags: arcpy

I want to create map overlays for a TomTom GPS. Relief shading, ortophoto etc as map background while navigating in Map View mode.

Instructions for creating custom overlay can be found [here](http://create.tomtom.com/manuals/create-your-own-content/index.html?map_overlays.htm)

So far I have download relief shading and ortophoto imagery from wms server for whole Estonia. (Relief shading and ortophoto would be separate overlays, I don't want to combine them.) That's over 12000 .jpg files for each. Files are 2000x2000 pixels (10x10km) in size (except tile files from last row and column, which are smaller).

What I need is to create one .sat file per each .jpg file.
.sat file is simple text file, similar to world file used by ESRI.
.sat file has same name as the .jpg it reffers to (except the extension)
.sat file contains 9 rows of information:

```
Line 1 - filename of the image file.
Line 2 - GPS coordinate of the top left corner of the image (longitude). 
Line 3 - GPS coordinate of the top left corner of the image (latitude).
Line 4 - GPS coordinate of the bottom right corner of the image (longitude).
Line 5 - GPS coordinate of the bottom right corner of the image (latitude).
Line 6 - Minimum zoom level for image to be visible (min = 0).
Line 7 - Maximum zoom level for image to be visible (max = 65,535).
Line 8 - Width of image file in pixels.
Line 9 - Height of image file in pixels.
```

So how could I generate such files automatically? I'm using ArcGIS.